# Simulink save final state leads to compile error

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simpe simulink model

[image: simulink model]

It compiles fine unless I try to save output states:

[image: save output states]

Then I face with this error when I try to compile it:

> Saving the complete set of the SimState is only supported for the model running in Normal or Accelerator mode, and for Model blocks running in Normal mode.

[image: matlab model error]

Why does it happen and how to get around that?

**Update:**

My model is set to fixed step and it is set to normal mode:
[image: simulink normal mode]

Comment: How do you run your model? Is it in a model block inside another model? Are you sure you don't have any other blocks in the model? Do you generate code from the model?

Comment: @am304, It is a very simple model. It is not nested. It runs fine. but it does not build. I build code by pressing the extreme right hand side button on the last photo that I have uploaded.

Comment: Why do you build the model? What purpose does that serve? Logging final states won't work with building. Just press play to run the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, "building" the model is only for the purpose of generating code/executables, and saving final states is not supported for code generation. If you just want to run the model, just press the "Run" button, not the "Build" button and it should work. See the [Simulink documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/interactive.html) for more details on how to run a model.

Comment: I need to run the simulink in a loop and tune the model at the beginning of each loop. Therefore, I need to the states to resume the simulink in the next loops. The problem is that simulink is normally very slow. Hence, I need to compile it to make it faster.

Comment: As I said that won't work. Simulink *is not* slow. Your model may be slow, but that's a different matter. I would try and address the causes for your model being slow and speed it up instead.

Comment: You cannot help me in this case, since the model is running in 5 to 10 seconds which is reasonable. I have done my best to make it as fast as possible. The problem is that it must run in a loop thousands of times which makes it very slow.

Comment: Well, without looking at the model, it's impossible to say whether 5/10s is reasonable or not. It might be OK or it might be that the model can run a lot faster. For example, I noticed in your "toy model" example that you are using a fixed-step solver. If you are also doing this in your "real" model, a variable-step solver might potentially be a lot faster.

Comment: Also see [Save and Restore Simulation State as SimState](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/saving-and-restoring-the-simulation-state-as-the-simstate.html) in the Simulink documentation for limitations on using `SimState`. You should be able to run your model in Accelerator, but however way you are running your model, I am convinced you do not need to press the "Build" button, it's completely unnecessary.